# How to abort/cancel a running command in initramfs?

Tags: command-line, initramfs

When I invoke a long-running command, e.g. `du`, I don't see a way to abort/cancel it (<kbd>Strg/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> doesn't work), other shells/ttys aren't available. Am I completely doomed after having started a long running command?

The initial line say shell is `ash` of `BusyBox` v1.22.1 (of course `ash` doesn't provide a `-V/--version` option).

Comment: did you try `Ctrl c`? Also what shell are you in bash? and what runlevel?